# How to mock api call in this example?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

I am not sure how to mock this API call in a `unit-test` for Vue

What's throwing me off is the variables that make up the API's url.

```js
export default {
  name: "Jobs",
  data() {
    return {
      job_execs: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.JobExecEndpoint = process.env.VUE_APP_UATU_URL + '/api/v1/job_execution/?tool='+this.$route.params.tool+'&job='+this.$route.params.job+'&id='+this.$route.params.id
     fetch(this.JobExecEndpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      this.job_execs.push({
        'code_checkouts': body[0].code_checkouts,
      })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```